# Euclidean division and negative numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to understand Euclidean division
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)

I am trying to do an example, and I am getting two different answers depending on where I have the negative sign:

9/(-4) = (-2)R1  [9 = (-4)*(-2) + 1]

(-9)/4 = (-3)R3  [-9 = 4*(-3) + 3]

How can this be? Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong. It's fine.

Comment: Thanks - I thought the result should be same.  Now I know better :) Also came across another question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338304/modulo-and-euclidean-division-is-wikipedia-correct-or-not?rq=1